# CakePHP 3 htaccess ignore directory

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp-3.x

After a lot of research I'm still struggling.

My `./.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/trackparser/.*$

    RewriteRule    ^(\.well-known/.*)$ $1 [L]
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

However, if I go to `www.mysite.com/trackparser` it just gives me a missing controller error.

How do I make it ignore the trackparser directory?

Comment: I believe that by including the trailing / in your condition, you're requiring that it be there. `www.mysite.com/trackparser` does not have that slash in it, so it's not matching.

Comment: Also conditions only apply to the first following rule. There's an easy fix, but first, is your domains document root actually pointing above the `webroot` folder, ie to the folder that _contains_ the `webroot` folder?

Comment: @ndm yes. It's pointing to the folder that has all the CakePHP files/folders including `webroot`.

Comment: @GregSchmidt I've changed it and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the required `/` as mentioned by @GregSchmidt, rewrite conditions only apply to the first rule that is following them, so your config basically says:

```sh
IF (URI != ^/trackparser/.*$) {
    RewriteRule ^(\.well-known/.*)$ $1 [L]
}

RewriteRule ^$    webroot/  [L]
RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
```

What you want is to apply all three rules if the URI doesn't match `^/trackparser/.*$`. To achieve that you can invert the condition and use a skipping rule, which when applied, will skip *N* number of the subsequent rules:

```sh
RewriteRule ^(\.well-known/.*)$ $1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/trackparser(/.*|$)
RewriteRule . - [S=2]

RewriteRule ^$   webroot/   [L]
RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
```

This will skip the `2` CakePHP webroot rules in case the condition is met, so it's basically doing:

```sh
RewriteRule ^(\.well-known/.*)$ $1 [L]

IF (URI != ^/trackparser(/.*|$)) {
    RewriteRule ^$   webroot/   [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
}
```

Note the removed negation operator, and the added `(/.*|$)` to make the ending slash optional. The rule for the `well-known` directory (certificate validation) could theoretically also be skipped, but I'd make it exempt in order to avoid it accidentally not being applied because of later changes.

See also

- **[Apache > HTTP Server > Documentation > Version 2.4 > Modules > Apache Module mod_rewrite > RewriteCond Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)**
- **[Apache > HTTP Server > Documentation > Version 2.4 > Rewrite > RewriteRule Flags > S|skip](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_s)**